# how can create Unique Constraint with multi column with entityframework

Tags: entity-framework, ef-fluent-api

I'm use Entityframework Code First, and an EntityTypeConfiguration using fluent API. 
how can create Unique Constraint with multi column. 
for example i have a table with below field

- Id
- CompanyId
- Code
- Name

i want set Code column to unique , per CompanyId

Comment: Please provide example data rather than just bullet point fields. Also please show us what you have tried so far

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your EntityTypeConfiguration you can do something like this:

```
Property(m => m.CompanyId)
    .HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("IX_YourUniqueIndexName", 1) { IsUnique = true }));
Property(m => m.Code)
    .HasColumnAnnotation("Index", new IndexAnnotation(new IndexAttribute("IX_YourUniqueIndexName", 2) { IsUnique = true }));
```

This will create a unique index on those 2 columns.

Make sure you use the same name for the unique index. Both need to be name "IX_YourUniqueIndex". If one is called "IX_Index1" and the other "IX_Index2" then it will create a unique index on each, which is not what you want