# Create unique constraint, unique itemNo per Account

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a table with the following schema, which basically contains **items** unique per each **account**, but **items** and **account** are not unique for the entire table.

```
EnteredDate  Account  ItemNo  ItemDesc
01/01/2018   1234     9982-1  TestItem1
01/01/2018   1234     9982-2  TestItem2
01/01/2018   1234     9982-3  TestItem3
01/01/2018   6789     9982-1  TestItem1
01/01/2018   6789     9982-4  TestItem4
```

I did saw a solution here but not 100% sure I should have the Account unique since this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31130642/how-can-create-unique-constraint-with-multi-column-with-entityframework?rq=1) shows that .

```
Model
public DateTime? EnteredDate { get; set; }

[StringLength(12)]
[Index("IX_TestItemNoPerAccount", 1, IsUnique = true)]
[Required]
public string Account { get; set; }

[StringLength(20)]
[Index("IX_TestItemNoPerAccount", 2, IsUnique = true)]
[Required]
public string ItemNo { get; set; }

[StringLength(500)]
[Required]
public string ItemDesc { get; set; }
```

So Should I have Account Unique or I should remove it? Thanks!

Comment: `So Should I have Account Unique or I should remove it?`-No! your current set up is  good enough for items unique per each account

Comment: So this is how it is supposed to setup? Got it!